How can I compute the conjugate of an integer partition?
I have a nonincreasing sequence of positive integers, say {2,1,1}.  I want the conjugate partition, i.e., the partition formed by transposing the Ferrer's diagram.  In other words, what I want is the conjugate of {2,1,1} which is {3,1}.

There's a resource function called ConjugatePartition. It works in the following manner:
l = {2, 1, 1};
ResourceFunction["ConjugatePartition"][l]

In the link you can find more examples.
Edit:
When we refer to any resource function, in the link there's something called source code. This allows you to download the notebook and see the custom command and how you can reconstruct it. It's a good way to understand what's happening and get extra knowledge.
In this case you can see these commands below:
custom@{} = {};
custom[p_] := Total[UnitStep[Outer[Plus, p, -Range[First[p]]]]]

And now you don't need to use ResourceFunction["ConjugatePartition"][l] but rather
custom[l]

to get your result.

I entered the code you have above and I get nothing.  I get an indication that the code is running but it never returns anything.

@GeoffreyCritzer, which version of Mathematica are you using? Are you connected to the internet?

I am using 12.1.   I am connected to the internet.

@GeoffreyCritzer see the edit

An approach:
p = {2, 1, 1};
cp[u_] := Total /@ Transpose[PadRight[Table[1, #] & /@ u]]
cp[p]

-> {3,1}
For fun:
vis[u_] := Module[{fd = PadRight[Table[1, #] & /@ u], fdt},
  fdt = Transpose[fd];
  Row[{
    ArrayPlot[fd, GridLines -> (Range /@ Reverse[Dimensions[fd]]), 
     GridLinesStyle -> Directive[White, Thick], PlotLabel -> u],
    ArrayPlot[fdt, GridLines -> (Range /@ Reverse[Dimensions[fdt]]), 
     GridLinesStyle -> Directive[White, Thick], 
     PlotLabel -> (Total /@ fdt)]
    }]]

Some examples:
vis[{2,1,1}]
vis[{2, 2, 1, 1}]
vis[{4, 2, 1}]



(+1) hats off for the visualisation!!! Amazing stuff

cp[u:{___Integer}] := Total /@ Transpose[PadRight[Table[1, #] & /@ u]] is more selective.

@Somos thank you for comment: I did this on the run and you are right about  the domain being lists of integers and also I didn’t deal with empty list.

Using ConstantArray and transposing ragged arrays:
Clear[conjugatePartition];
conjugatePartition[k_List] := Module[{},
  k /. v_Integer :> ConstantArray[1, v] // Flatten[#, {{2}, {1}}] & //
    Map[Length]
  ]

Using ArrayMesh to visualize:
Clear[vis];
vis[k_List] := 
 Module[{}, k /. v_Integer :> ConstantArray[1, v]] // PadRight[#] &

{#, conjugatePartition[#]} &@{3, 2, 1, 1} // Echo[#] & // Map[vis] //  
  Map[
   ArrayMesh[#
     , PlotLabel -> Count[1] /@ #
     , MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Lighter@Green
       , {1, All} -> Black
       }
     , ImageSize -> {80, 80}
     ] &] //
 GraphicsRow



This can also be used to visualize many partitions at a time as follows:
IntegerPartitions[6]


{{6}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 1, 1}, {3, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, {2,
2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}

IntegerPartitions[6] /. n_Integer :> ConstantArray[1, n] // PadRight //
 ArrayMesh[#
   , MeshCellHighlight -> {
     {2, All} -> Red, {1, All} -> Black
     }
   , SphericalRegion -> True
   ] &



EDIT
GroupBy[IntegerPartitions[6], conjugatePartition] /. 
  Association :> List // TableForm


